# Getline only printing out last line when called multiple times

Tags: c++, file-io, getfiles

So this is a fairly simple example of a program where I'm trying to output the first two lines of an input text file.  The ifstream should be a global variable, and the testGetFile() function is necessary (I have not done the actual text processing needed in this code.)  I'm trying to figure out why this is cout-ing only the SECOND line of the input file.  Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
ifstream input;

string testGetFile(){
    string result;
    getline(input,result);
    return result;
}

int main(){
    input.open("testInput.txt");
    cout<< testGetFile();
    cout<< testGetFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me, try appending an `endl`.

Comment: Hmm, it's working now.  Do you know why it does this with an endl?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: It does the same thing, it is just that without it, it looks like one line when printing it.

Comment: Interesting...  Might be something weird with my display.  It only shows the last line without the endl for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: It seems that it printed both lines in one single line and you didn't notice the first line being printed on the same line as the second one. You only saw the second line being printed, because your eye processed the output of your program from right to left ;)